# How to share an object between Java classes?

Tags: java

I have three java class ( A.java & B.java & C.java ) that all of them located in a common package . I want to make an object of class B ( instanceOfB ) in class A and could use that object in class C . How do that ? Thanks

```
public class A{
   public B instanceOfB;
}

public class B{ 
}

public class C{ 
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - flesh out the requirement a bit

Comment: Just... have a B member in C and set both the A and C member to the same object? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a getter method to retrieve the instance of class B from the A object and use it in C:

```
public B getB() {
   return this.B;
}
```

Comment: That just kicks the can down the road, now the `C` needs access to an `A` instance.

Answer (score 0):

*Somehow* you need to pass the instance of `B` to `C` during construction. The simplest way is to have a constructor on `C`:

```
public class C {
  private B myInstanceOfB;
 
  public C(B instance) {
    this.myInstanceOfB = instance;
  }
}
```

Now this would mean that whoever creates a `C` instance must know to do that and have access to a `B` instance. It's possible that you want to "hide" that requirement, then you can do things like add a factory method for `C` into the `A` class:

```
public class A {
  private B instanceOfB;

  public C createC() {
    return new C(instanceOfB);
  }
}
```

If you do this you can also make the `C` constructor package-private to indicate to potential users that they should not attempt to instantiate it directly (and document in the JavaDoc how to get a `C` instance).

Whether or not that makes sense depends on what the relation between A and C is.